# Dynamic user ranks

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a basic karma/rep system that awards users based on their activities (questions, answers, etc..). I want to have user ranks (title) based on their points. Different ranks have different limitations and grant powers.

ranks table

```
id    rankname   points   questions_per_day
 1    beginner   150      10
 2    advanced   300      30
```

I'm not sure if I need to have a lower and upper limit, but for the sake of simplicity I have only left a max points limit, that is, a user below 150 is a 'beginner' and below or higher than 300, he's an 'advanced'.

For example, Bob with 157 points would have an 'advanced' tag displayed by his username.

How can I determine and display the rank/title of an user? Do I loop through each row and compare values?

What problems might arise if I scale this to thousands of users having their rank calculated this way? Surely it will tax the system to query and loop each time a user's rank is requested, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could better cache the rank and the score. If a user's score only changes when they do certain activities, you can put a trigger on that activity. When the score changes, you can recalculate the rank and save it in the users record. That way, retreiving the rank is trivial, you only need to calculate it when the score changes.

You can get the matching rank id like this; query the rank that is closest (but below or equal to) the user schore. Store this rank id in the user's record.
I added the pseudovariable {USERSCORE} because I don't know if you use parameters or any other way to enter values in a query.

```
select r.id
from ranks r
where r.points <= {USERSCORE}
order by r.points desc
limit 1
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I already manage user scores this way. I need to determine their rank/title based on a table.

Comment: Well then, replace `score` with `rank` in my answer to answer the second part of your question. Will post an addition in a second.

Comment: Added the query to calculate the rank id based on a score. You can use this real time or cache it in the user table, whatever you like. You can use this id to get the right rank name to display on the user page. If you use this query realtime (which will probably perform just fine as long as you don't have thousands of users), you'd better replace `r.id` with `r.rankname` right away, so you don't have to execute a second query.

Answer (score 1):

A little difficult without knowing your schema. Try:

```
SELECT user.id, MIN(ranks.id) AS rankid FROM user JOIN ranks ON (user.score <= ranks.points) GROUP BY user.id;
```

Now you know the ranks id.

This is non-trivial though (GROUP BY and MAX are pipeline breakers and so quite heavyweight operations), so GolezTrol advice is good; you should cache this information and update it only when a users score changes. A trigger sounds fine for this.

Comment: I'm unsure of why you used MAX because it will only return the max rank in the table, otherwise it's great.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean with max rank in the table. It will give you the highest rank from all joined rows. All joined rows from rank must be equal to or lower than the user score. So it will give you the highest rank that fits the users score or lower. It should fit.

Comment: I just tried this. A users table with two items (Bob with 11 points and Jim with 299). With MAX it shows rankid for both of them as 2 (taken from the ranks table in OP). Removing MAX displays 1 and 2 accordingly, as it should.

Comment: You're right, my bad. It should be MIN instead of MAX (as we're cutting away ranks below the users score). I wouldn't rely on implicit row ordering done by MySQL, as you are when you do not use an aggregate function. It can change when you change the ranks table contents. I've edited my answer to correct the error.